# How do I save an image with file name defined in the text box?

Tags: c#

Save button should save the file as a JPEG with the file name defined in the 
text box. Then load the saved image in another form.

So far I have the following code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlDraw.Width, pnlDraw.Height);

            pnlDraw.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0,
                pnlDraw.Width, pnlDraw.Height));

            bmp.Save(saveDialog.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Comment: Looks sensible - what's the issue with it?

Comment: It doesn't show the file name from the text box. I need to save the file as the name from input of a text box.

Comment: What's saveDialog and where is it defined? What's the ID of the textbox?

Comment: Id? You mean the name it's txtModelName. Save Dialog is the windows that opens to save file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `ShowDialog()` give the name from the textbox to the dialog:

```
saveDialog.FileName = txtModelName.Text;
```

(this is only correct, if you have the complete path incl. directory in your textbox)

Answer (score -1):

I'm making a few assumptions as I don't know what `saveDialog` is but you could just replace it with the value from your textbox

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlDraw.Width, pnlDraw.Height);

    pnlDraw.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlDraw.Width, pnlDraw.Height));

    bmp.Save(txtModelName.Text, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Notice I've taken out the `saveDialog` altogether (after all you don't want to ask them where to save twice), if you do want to confirm then perhaps you need a `MessageBox`?

Comment: Thanks Liath this answer still helped me.